# Safari 8 mac os animation-delay issue

Tags: css, safari, css-animations

I have this peace of code:

```css
.loader {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  position: relative
}
.loader .circle:before,
.loader .circle:after,
.loader:after,
.loader:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #183546;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-animation: 1.76s bounce_circularG infinite;
  animation: bounce_circularG 1.76s infinite
}
.loader:before {
  left: 0;
  top: 25px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .66s;
  animation-delay: .66s
}
.loader:after {
  left: 7px;
  bottom: 7px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.2s;
  animation-delay: 2.2s
}
.loader .circle_1:before {
  left: 7px;
  top: 7px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .88s;
  animation-delay: .88s
}
.loader .circle_1:after {
  top: 0;
  left: 25px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.1s;
  animation-delay: 1.1s
}
.loader .circle_2:before {
  right: 7px;
  top: 7px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.32s;
  animation-delay: 1.32s
}
.loader .circle_2:after {
  right: 0;
  top: 25px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.54s;
  animation-delay: 1.54s
}
.loader .circle_3:before {
  right: 7px;
  bottom: 7px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.76s;
  animation-delay: 1.76s
}
.loader .circle_3:after {
  left: 25px;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.98s;
  animation-delay: 1.98s
}
.tab-content .loader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -32px
}
@-webkit-keyframes bounce_circularG {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1)
  }
  35% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(.3)
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1)
  }
}
@keyframes bounce_circularG {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(.3)
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">
  <div class="circle circle_1"></div>
  <div class="circle circle_2"></div>
  <div class="circle circle_3"></div>
</div>
```

In chrome and opera everything works nice, but safari 8 strongly ignores child's animation-delay until I make a hard DOM reflow.

```
$('.loader').hide();
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.loader').hide();
}, 15);
```

I don't like such a dirty hacks, do anybody know how to fix it with pure css?

Edit:
I found a bit better hack, but it is still a hack, how to make it nice?

```
@-webkit-keyframes bounce_circularG {
    0%      {display: none;-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
    1%      {display: block;}
    35%     {-webkit-transform:scale(.3)}
    100%    {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}
```

Comment: `-webkit-animation: 1.76s bounce_circularG infinite;` is invalid due to ignoring order `name | duration | timing | delay`

Comment: @Pepo_rasta browser renders it in a same manner, this correction doesn't fix the bug